# Editor for new programming language in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, ide, eclipse-plugin, programming-languages, antlr

I really hope someone can help me out with this!

For the GOAL Agent Programming language, there is an existing IDE written in JEdit, which is not that good. Thus, we wanted to migrate the editing (at least) to the Eclipse platform.

The GOAL programming language involves several other filetypes on its own, including Prolog files for instance. To this end, a few grammars written in ANTLR exist, which work quite well.

My question now is, using these pre-existing grammars and built lexers/parsers and such, is it possible to easily create an Eclipse editor for this?

I have looked at some existing stuff, like Xtext (would have to write a new grammar, which probably is not even possible for GOAL or Prolog), IMP (abandoned a few years ago already?), etcetera. None of these seem to suffice.

Does anyone have any ideas/suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not really familiar with Xtext, but why wouldn't it be possible to write a GOAL and/or Prolog grammar in it?

Comment: So far, I have only seen examples of some small domain specific languages. It does not seem possible to for instance have an embedded language structure (Prolog sections in GOAL files), and we'd have to maintain two grammars for everything (ANTLR to actually parse stuff and Xtext to display stuff), which would be inconvenient

Comment: I would have guessed the embedded Prolog code would be handled by the lexer/scanner part of Xtext, unless you're hoping to parse both languages (in which case you'd need 2 ANTLR grammars as well). But again, I'm not familiar with Xtext: I'm sure you've spend more time researching it than I have. I was just curious.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is http://www.eclipse.org/dltk/ not sure if you evaluated it already or not.
It doesn't pretend to generate the whole IDE for you :-) However, it abstracts common functionality, so you can focus mostly on your language features.

Comment: Thanks! I have indeed seen that one too. However, in the tutorials, they use some example parsers and such which they do not go into, but which are required. So not much ANTLR coupling possible there I guess

Comment: You can use any technology in your parser. What is highly recommended is implementing _source element parser_, so you can report structure of your file (types/methods/fields). Which is used to display outline, for "open type" functionality, etc.

Comment: So, I would have to implement a new parser, correct? In addition, I really cannot find anything at DLTK which allows me to integrate an existing lexer/parser

Comment: You can create ISourceParser implementation, call your existing parser and return AST + errors to DLTK. DLTK will display errors in the problems view and cache the AST. The idea of ISourceElementParser is that you use your AST, select types/methods/fields and report them to DLTK. DLTK knows nothing about your AST, so you have to implement some code on your own.

Comment: Oke, thanks, interesting! Can you perhaps point me to any tutorial/example that implements it like that?

Answer (score 0):

It is unfortunate that IMP indeed seems abandoned, as it covers exactly your scenario: your language, compiler, etc. is working already and now you need "just" the IDE.

Nevertheless, IMP is still working, and recently, it has been used to implement the IDE for the [Frege programming language](https://github.com/Frege).

Comment: Yeah, it seemed the best for me too, but indeed the abandonment (no future prospects) and lack of documentation (proper ANTLR support is mentioned 'coming soon' since december 2009) are a really negative factor, which to me also degrades the Eclipse platform a bit